Distribution of MLE Ratio for Pareto Parameters
I am working on a problem involving two groups of independent random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ and $Y_1, \dots, Y_5$, both following Pareto distributions but with different shape parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. Specifically:

For the first group, $X_i \sim \text{Pareto}(\theta_1)$ with the PDF:

$$f_{\theta_1}(x) = \theta_1 (1 + x)^{-(\theta_1 + 1)} \, \mathbb{I}_{(0, \infty)}(x),$$

For the second group, $Y_i \sim \text{Pareto}(\theta_2)$ with the PDF:

$$f_{\theta_2}(x) = \theta_2 (1 + x)^{-(\theta_2 + 1)} \, \mathbb{I}_{(0, \infty)}(x).$$
All variables are independent, and the parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are unknown. My task is to test:
$$H_0: \frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2} = 2 \quad \text{against} \quad H_1: \frac{\theta_1}{\theta_2} < 2$$
at a significance level $\alpha = 0.05$. The critical region is defined as:
$$C = \left\{ \frac{\hat{\theta}_1}{\hat{\theta}_2} < c \right\},$$
where $\hat{\theta}_1$ and $\hat{\theta}_2$ are the maximum likelihood estimators of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, respectively.
What I have so far:
I derived the MLE for the Pareto shape parameter as:
$$\hat{\theta} = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n \log(1+x_i)},$$
where $n$ is the sample size, and $x_i$ are the observed values. I suspect that finding the critical constant $c$ requires determining the distribution of the ratio $\frac{\hat{\theta}_1}{\hat{\theta}_2}$, but I am stuck because I don't know the exact distribution of this statistic.
Question:
How can I determine the distribution of the ratio $\frac{\hat{\theta}_1}{\hat{\theta}_2}$ for the MLEs of the Pareto shape parameters? Any hints, references, or derivations would be greatly appreciated!
